Stanley's review of Macdonald's book (Symmetric functions and Hall polynomials)
I'm working through chapter IV of Macdonald's book, finding it somewhat complex due to its use of notations and concepts from earlier chapters. To get a clearer understanding, I looked up a review by Stanley, available on his website: https://math.mit.edu/~rstan/pubs/pubfiles/49.pdf.
In page 260, he writes: Let $\lambda=(\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_l)$ be a partition of $n$ and let $P=P_\lambda$ be the parabolic subgroup of $G=\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{F}_q)$ associated to $\lambda$. Let $\eta_\lambda(q)$ be the character of $\operatorname{Ind}_{P}^G(1)$. He claims there exist irreducible characters $\chi^\mu(q)$ of $\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{F}_q)$ such that
$$
\eta_\lambda(q)=\sum_{\mu}K_{\lambda\mu}\chi^\mu(q). \tag{1}\label{476211_1}
$$
He also states that the value of $\chi^\lambda(q)$ at a unipotent element of type $\mu$ is
$$
q^{n(\mu)-n(\lambda)}K_{\lambda\mu}(q^{-1}).\tag{2}\label{476211_2}$$
I have two questions about these claims:
Regarding formula \eqref{476211_1}, if we take $\lambda = (1,1,\dots,1)$, meaning $P_\lambda$ is the Borel subgroup $B$, then $K_{\lambda\mu} = 0$ unless $\mu = \lambda$, where $K_{\lambda\lambda} = 1$. This suggests that $\operatorname{Ind}_{B}^G(1)$ is irreducible which I am not sure if this is correct. Could there be a typo in Stanley's claim, or am I overlooking something? What would be the accurate statement if the claim needs correction?
Regarding formula \eqref{476211_2}, I couldn't find this assertion in Macdonald's book. Where can I find a reference for this?

$Ind_B^G(1)$ is certainly reducible in general and $K_{\lambda\mu}=\dim(\pi_\mu)$ where $\pi_\mu$ is the representation of $S_n$ corresponding to the partition $\mu$.

Indeed, any character induced from the trivial character of a subgroup has the trivial character of the larger group with multiplicity $1$.

@KentaSuzuki: Here I am taking $\lambda=(1^n)$ and so $K_\lambda\mu$ is not what you wrote. Indeed $K_{\lambda\mu}=0$, when $\mu\neq \lambda$. The reason is  $K_{\lambda\mu}\neq 0$ if and only if $\mu\unlhd \lambda$. Note that $K_{\mu\lambda}=\dim(\pi_\mu)$.

@MarkWildon: I agree with you, this is why I think the first formula is not correct. Do you know the right statement?

I posted an answer. (It started as a comment, but since I believe it's right and  I wanted to give some context, it became too long.) I don't think you will find the second formula in MacDonald: Stanley comments parenthetically in his review 'These characters are not mentioned as such by Macdonald, since they play no special role in the theory as he develops it.' Instead I suggest you try the paper of Steinberg cited by Stanley.

The analogous formula for the permutation characters of the symmetric group induced from Young subgroups is that $\mathrm{Ind}_{S_\lambda}^{S_n} 1_{S_\lambda} = \sum_{\mu \unrhd \lambda} K_{\mu\lambda} \chi^\mu$. For instance the case $\lambda = (1^n)$ is the regular representation.
It therefore appears that there is a typo and $\mu$ and $\lambda$ should be swapped in the formula in Stanley's review to give
$$\eta_\lambda(q) = \sum_{\mu \unrhd \lambda} K_{\mu\lambda}\chi^\mu(q).$$
Then taking $\lambda = (1^n)$ we get $\eta_{(1^n)}(q) = \sum_{\mu} K_{\mu(1^n)}(q)\chi^\mu(q) = \sum_{\mu} |\mathrm{SYT}(\mu)|\chi^\mu(q)$, corresponding to the fact that every unipotent character appears in the induction of the trivial character of the Borel. And taking $\lambda = (n)$ when the parabolic subgroup $P_{(n)}$ is the full general linear group, we get  $\eta_{(n)}(q) = \chi^{(n)}(q) = 1_{\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{F}_q)}$, also correct.

I agree: it should be $K_{\mu\lambda}$.

@MarkWildon: Thanks for your answer. I found this paper (The unipotent modules of GLn(Fq) via tableaux, Scott Andrews). Proposition 2, page 6, of this paper states that $\eta_\lambda(q)=\sum_{\mu}K_{\mu'\lambda}\chi^\mu(q)$. He didn't provide any proof. There might be no contradiction to your answer, since his construction of $\chi^\mu$ might be different than yours. Can you please comment on this?

Yes, it seems there is a conjugation in the paper you cite. Please read before Proposition 3.2: 'Note that $\chi^{(1^n)}$ [conventions of the paper] is the
trivial character and $\chi^{(n)}$ is the Steinberg character. As the trivial character is indexed by the transpose of $(n)$ (rather than by $(n)$ as with the symmetric group), we should expect our results to be transposed to some extent.' Stanley's convention agrees with James' in his lecture notes on the general linear group and later work on Hecke algebras.
